# What is apache poi method to get sheet xml from xlsx file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

What is apache poi method to get sheet xml from xlsx file ?

Its intended to fetch that xml file and parse it using StAX parser.
They lie inside \xl\worksheets\ of xlsx archive

Answer (score 3):

If you look on the [Apache POI website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) (who'd have thought!), you'll see exactly what you need for getting all the sheet XMLs to process with SAX or StAX:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
SharedStringsTable sst = r.getSharedStringsTable();

Iterator<InputStream> sheets = r.getSheetsData();
while(sheets.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("Processing new sheet:\n");
    InputStream sheet = sheets.next();
    // Process sheet XML here
    sheet.close();
}
```

The key helper class for low level XML processing of XLSX files is [XSSFReader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.html)